# Find one key containing string in swift dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a `[String:String]` dictionary. I would like to get the value associated with any key containing the string "S". Order does not matter.

This is dead easy : just get all the keys, iterate, return the first matching the condition.

HOWEVER, I would like to do that using a swift-like elegant approach. Something using a `filter` or `map` functions. And that's where I get lost...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are only interested in *any* matching value,
you can use the `indexOf()` method to find the first matching
dictionary entry. This works because
 a dictionary is a collection of key/value pairs.

**Swift 2:**

```
let dict = ["foo": "bar", "PQRS": "baz"]
let searchTerm = "S"

if let index = dict.indexOf({ (key, _) in key.containsString(searchTerm) }) {
    let value = dict[index].1
    print(value)
} else {
    print("no match")
}
```

As soon as a matching key is found, the predicate returns `true`
and the enumeration stops. The `index` is a "dictionary index" which
can be used directly to get the corresponding dictionary entry.

For a case-insensitive key search, replace the predicate by

```
{
    (key, _) in  key.rangeOfString(searchTerm, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
}
```

In **Swift 3** you can use `first(where:)` to find the first matching
element, this saves one dictionary lookup:

```
if let entry = dict.first(where: { (key, _) in key.contains(searchTerm) }) {
    print(entry.value)
} else {
    print("no match")
}
```

For a case-insensitive key search, replace the predicate by

```
{
    (key, _) in key.range(of: searchTerm, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
}
```

Comment: if I do not need case insensitiveness because I know strings are all caps, can I use key.contains() instead of key.range() or is key.range() faster ?

Comment: @Adeline: I don't think it makes a difference, but `key.contains()` is simpler, so I would use that.

Comment: All three answers are valid, but his one is the fastest.

Comment: @richc: The Swift 3 version should work with Swift 4 as well – let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: How would I check if any **values** for the keys match? So if any values match put those **keys** that have matching values into a new **matchedArray**. Basically sorting keys by matching values. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with `flatMap` and `containsString`:

**Swift 2.x**:

```
let dict = ["one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3", "four": "4", "five": "5", "six": "6"]

let results = dict.flatMap { (key, value) in key.lowercaseString.containsString("o") ? value : nil }

print(results)
```

Output:

> ```
> ["4", "1", "2"]
> ```

```
print(results.first ?? "Not found")
```

> ```
> 4
> ```

Or if you love cryptic one liners:

```
let first = dict.flatMap { $0.lowercaseString.containsString("o") ? $1 : nil }.first ?? "Not found"
```

---

For **Swift 3**:

```
let dict = ["one": "1", "two": "2", "three": "3", "four": "4", "five": "5", "six": "6"]

let results = dict.flatMap { (key, value) in key.lowercased().contains("o") ? value : nil }

print(results)
print(results.first ?? "Not Found")
```

Or if you love cryptic one liners:

```
let first = dict.flatMap { $0.lowercased().contains("o") ? $1 : nil }.first ?? "Not Found"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `filter`, `contains` and `first` to find "s":

*Swift 2*

```
if let key = yourDictionary.keys.filter({ $0.lowercaseString.characters.contains("s") }).first, let result = yourDictionary[key] {
    print(result)
}
```

*Swift 3*

```
if let key = yourDictionary.keys.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains("s") }).first, let result = yourDictionary[key] {
    print(result)
}
```

In a comment, [@Hamish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2976878/hamish) offers this excellent alternative for Swift 3: instead of

```
filter({ ... }).first
```

you can use

```
first(where: { ... })
```

Example:

```
if let key = yourDictionary.keys.first(where: { $0.lowercased().contains("s") }), let result = yourDictionary[key] {
    print(result)
}
```

Comment: Note that in Swift 3, you can also use [`first(where:)`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/Sequence/#func-first_) to do this.

Comment: @Hamish This is an excellent idea, thanks. Are you going to use it in an answer, or do I add it to mine (with attribution of course)?

Comment: @EricD I don't mind :) I notice that Martin has also used it in his answer (spooky timing there!), so I don't really see any point in me making a separate answer for it.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks. Sometimes including a comment in an answer can seem awkward, so I wanted to have your ok. ;)

Comment: @Hamish: I do not know what "spooky" means in this context, but I hope that you believe that I arrived independently at that solution. I definitely needed more than 20 seconds to write and test that code :)

Comment: @MartinR Of course – from my perspective, your edit happened at the *exact* same moment that I posted the comment (therefore no dispute over its independence), hence "spooky" :)